# are those mold? and are these dangerous?

Tags: bathroom, mold

Me and my wife are having headaches and fatigue lately, and we are not sure what's causing it. We did some research and found https://www.whatsupfagans.com/black-mold-in-showers/ and realize it could be caused by mold in our condo. I did a quick search around my condo and saw those black spots in the bathroom (second picture is the backside of the bathroom door). Not sure if they are mold, and want to get some second opinions in the forum. And those black spots have been there for a while already.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like mold / mildew yes it can be killed with a bleach & water solution or a hydrogen peroxide and water mixture. Is it the “bad stuff” only testing will reveal that but to tell the truth that doesn’t look that bad. But killing it and keeping the area dry, making sure the vent fan is on when using the shower / bath will help get the moisture out that is allowing the mold to grow. I prefer 3% hydrogen peroxide and water AAA (always add acid to water to prevent an exothermic reaction.

Comment: does it look like there is leaking or mold growing on the backside of bathtub?